# ubuntu cloud service and CarotDAV

Tags: cloud

I am trying to connect to Ubuntu cloud service one.Ubuntu.com  with 3th client carotdav.
 On windows7 home, 64 bit.(limited user, non-administrator)
Does it possible? In theory yes, but in reality  I need your help...

carotdav says:

```
Rei.Fs.SimpleWebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
   at Rei.Fs.Webdav.WebdavFs.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean notreqstream)
   at Rei.Fs.Webdav.WebdavFs.InnerGetInfo(Uri target, DepthType depth)
   at Rei.Fs.Webdav.WebdavFs.GetInfoAndEntries(Uri targeturi)
   at CarotDAV.CacheManager.GetInfoAndEntries(FsBase fs, Uri targeturi, Boolean enablecache)
   at CarotDAV.MainForm.Fs_GetInfoAndInnerEntries(Uri uri, ResourceId id, ResourceId parentid, Boolean enablecache)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu One does not provide a WebDAV interface for file storage, no.